# Http not redirecting to Https when click on http URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have installed SSL and did all the setting in wordpress like see the screenshot: `http://prntscr.com/d46lfv`

Also add code in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.copybloggerthemes\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://copybloggerthemes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I redirected my site `http://copybloggerthemes.com` to `https://copybloggerthemes.com` 
All pages/posts are now seen as https, but when i try to click on **http link** then it does not redirect to **https link**. why

**example:** `http://copybloggerthemes.com/straight-blogger-template/`
This does not redirect to https. Same issue with all posts and pages except homepage.

Comment: Either you are simply looking at cached results (clear your browser cache) or yout `.htaccess` file is not evaluated by the http server. That can happen if either it is located in the wrong place or if such files have not been enabled.

Comment: @arkascha please look into the .htaccess file in the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/d46wpy let me know if that is incorrect

Comment: Ok, that explains. You have to change the order of the rules, currently yours are never reached. The wordpress rules above will rewrite all requests and then bail out. Place your rules first.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess, Its an exact copy of the one I currently use in my .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

<del>EDIT: I should also point out I'm struggling to get redirected to a none https page of your site.</del>

Comment: Are you using it alongside the code you placed in the question or did you replace it with mine?

Comment: i have added your code provided by you. I save the file and come back and check the http url in addressbar but it was not redirecting to https.

Comment: Empty your .htaccess and _only_ place mine in. Then check if it works.

Comment: Make sure you take a backup incase you break anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^copybloggerthemes\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.copybloggerthemes.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please use the above code in the htaccess. Next use the below code to add it anywhere in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Check this and let us know.